# Most efficient way to create an array of length n filled with unique symbols

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I need to create an array of variable length where each element is a unique symbol. Is there a built-in (ES6) or lodash method to easily do this? What I have currently is `_.map(range(n), () => Symbol())` which is fairly efficient text and timewise, but I would prefer to replace `map` with a different function that allows me to replace `range(n)` with just `n`.

Comment: So use fill() ? `Array(10).fill(1)`

Comment: I just want to note that if you're using a polyfilled Symbol implementation like Babel's, they leak memory for every Symbol created, so if this is something you're doing often, it could be a big problem.

Comment: The node version I use (6.9.5) supports Symbol natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**times**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#times):

```
let result = _.times(5, () => Symbol())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.from({length: n}, () => Symbol())
```

would be one option.